# How can I check ModelState.IsValid from inside my Razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following in my action method:

```
       if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(vm);
```

In the view I want to not present a submit key to allow deletion if the model state is not valid. Is there a way that I can do this? Is model state available in the view?

Update: I have implemented this based on the answers I was given:

```
            <div class="adm_td0" style=" padding: 0;">  
            @if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid) {
                <input type='submit' value='Delete' name='SubmitAction' />
            }
                <input type='submit' value='Cancel' name='SubmitAction' />
            </div>
```

Comment: also ensure you are using Html.AntiForgeryToken. The delete action could easily be forged. You may not care - (could be a tiny internal application) but just an extra warning. Just because the button isn't showing doesn't mean it can't be called. Also I would check the modelstate on the server side as well on your post to ensure something didn't fail on the client side.

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/How-to-check-if-model-is-valid-inside-the-razor-view-in-Asp-Net-MVC

Answer (score 231, accepted):

> Is model state available in the view?

Of course:

```
@if (!ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    <div>There are some errors</div>
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a a way to check for specific errors, something like: @if (ViewData.ModelState.Errors["errorName"]) { // do something }

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out: Html.ViewData.ModelState["PropertyName"].Errors

Comment: I also used this to display a specific error in the validation summary, and it worked.
@if (ViewData.ModelState.Keys.Any(x => x == "ErrorKeyName"))
{
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "")  
}

Answer (score 14):

It's not common to need this in the view itself, but you can access it like so:

```
@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid
```

Comment: This will be for the previous request though. Not the request that is ABOUT to be submitted.

Comment: @ChrisKooken can you clarify what you mean re the requests?  My understanding is that the ModelState will contain the state of any errors from model binding for the request that is being processed at that time by the server.

Comment: @NormanH, when you use `@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid` in a *view*, it will tell you about the state of the model that was processed just prior to showing the view. So the flow is: view A -> press button and post -> controller: model binding before method B -> invalid state -> method B returns view B -> `@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid` will tell what happened while binding before method B