# How do I know if my form has validated from within my view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Currently, I'm setting `ViewBag.HasError` in my controller, then using that variable in my view to determine if the html providing the validation message should be written to screen.

start.cshtml:

```
@if (ViewBag.HasError != null && ViewBag.HasError)
{
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)<br />                
    </td>
  </tr>
}
```

is there something similar within the framework already?

Comment: The validation message will be empty if there are no errors.

Comment: @Maarten the 'validation message' may be empty, but I'd still be writing the html 'housing' to the screen everytime, which I dont want to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check ModelState.IsValid from inside my Razor view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506960/how-can-i-check-modelstate-isvalid-from-inside-my-razor-view)

Comment: @Anton, if I knew enough to ask 'how do I check ModelState.IsValid', then I wouldn't have asked the question... also, what is your username @Anton? (see what I did there?) Anyway, the answer massively helped me.

Comment: @Nnoel My comment was meant to help you by giving you a pointer to a similar question that was answered already. Sorry if my intention was unclear.

Comment: @Anton no apologies needed, I was just 'defending' my question from deletion, as I thought something like that would be the procedure for duplicates. anyway, may be duplicate, but Andrei's answer is better than the two answers in the duplicated question. lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need any flags for this, framework already has everything in place. When it comes to `ValidationMessageFor` execution, `ModelState` is checked to contain this specific message. If the message is found (meaning that the validation was done), it is displayed, otherwise this methods adds nothing to the output.

However there are some built-in features that allow you to check model state on the view. Here is how to check is the model is valid in general (similar to what you have implemented):

```
@ViewData.ModelState.IsValid
```

And here is how to check errors for specific field:

```
@ViewData.ModelState["Email"].Errors.Count != 0
```